# Oracle query using temporary table is failing with errors

Tags: oracle, large-data, temp-tables

I was trying to get a query which used multiple joins on a table with 25M records and took far too long to run. So I used a temporary table and then added a small section of the table and then ran the same query with the temporary table but it doesn't recognize my temporary table. My Oracle is nowhere near as strong as my SQL so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Test
(EVENTTIME Timestamp Default 0,
LCIDENTIFIER nvarchar2(50),
MESSAGETYPE nvarchar2(4),
ADDRIDENTIFIER nvarchar(50));

SELECT TOP(1000), LCIDENTIFIER, MESSAGETYPE, ADDRIDENTIFIER, EVENTTIME 
INTO #Test 
FROM TR_COMMUNICATION;

SELECT DELAYED.CREATEEVENTTIME,
   DELAYED.LREP_TIME,
   DELAYED.DLST_TIME,
   DELAYED.SOURCEADDRESS,
   NEXT_LREP.ADDRESSIDENTIFIER AS NEXT_LREP FROM (
SELECT tv.CREATEEVENTTIME,
   lrep_cc.EVENTTIME AS LREP_TIME,
   dlst_cc.EVENTTIME AS DLST_TIME,
   tv.SOURCEADDRESS,
   tr.FROM_POS,
   extract(second from dlst_cc.EVENTTIME - lrep_cc.EventTime) * 1000 as ms_diff
FROM TR_OVERVIEW_V tv
INNER JOIN TR_RELATED tr ON tr.LC_NAME = tv.LC_NAME 
                              AND tr.FROM_LOC = tv.SOURCEADDRESS
                              AND tr.EVENT_NAME = 'TaskStarted'
INNER JOIN Test lrep_cc ON lrep_cc.LCIDENTIFIER = tv.LC_NAME
                                         AND lrep_cc.MESSAGETYPE = 'LREP'
                                         AND lrep_cc.ADDRIDENTIFIER = tr.FROM_POS
                                         AND lrep_cc.EVENTTIME <= tv.CREATEEVENTTIME + 
interval '1' second
                                         AND lrep_cc.EVENTTIME >= tv.CREATEEVENTTIME - 
interval '1' second
INNER JOIN Test dlst_cc ON dlst_cc.LCIDENTIFIER = tv.LC_NAME
                                         AND dlst_cc.MESSAGETYPE = 'DLST'
                                         AND dlst_cc.EVENTTIME <= tv.CREATEEVENTTIME + 
interval '2' second
                                         AND dlst_cc.EVENTTIME >= tv.CREATEEVENTTIME - 
interval '2' second                                             
WHERE tv.EVENT_NAME = 'CompletedWithError'
AND tv.SOURCEADDRESS IS NOT NULL
AND extract(second from dlst_cc.EVENTTIME - lrep_cc.EventTime) * 1000 > 250
ORDER BY tv.EVENTTIME DESC
FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY) DELAYED
OUTER APPLY (SELECT ADDRIDENTIFIER
         FROM Test
         WHERE MESSAGETYPE = 'LREP'
         AND LCIDENTIFIER = DELAYED.LC_NAME
         AND EVENTTIME > DELAYED.DLST_TIME
         ORDER BY EVENTTIME ASC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) NEXT_LREP;
```

Comment: `select top` is not valid in Oracle, and you don't "select into" a table in PL/SQL. You *insert*. What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"? What errors are you getting back? There are likely far more efficient ways to do this than using a temporary table. Have you considered materialized views?

Comment: Your table creation is also invalid - `nvarchar` instead of `nvarchar2`, and `default 0` isn't valid for a timestamp column. You seem to be mixing syntax from other databases (SQL Server?) with Oracle. I would also question whether populating the then using a temporary table is going to be more efficient that joining to the original table - that seems unlikely, unless perhaps you're running many queries against that in the same session, and even then it might not help.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1000), ...` is not valid as Oracle does not support the `TOP` syntax. If you have implemented a user-defined function called `TOP` then that is not something that is standard and we will not have it available to us.

Comment: As an aside, Oracle SQL is an SQL dialect. I am assuming that you mean "my Oracle SQL is nowhere near as strong as my SQL Server SQL" as there are not any databases that I know of that strictly implement ANSI/ISO standard SQL; they all have their own idiosyncratic SQL dialects.

Comment: The original query is present and 'the TR_RELATED has over 25M records so with the multiple joins it takes far too long. I haven't used Oracle in a very long time so apologies for the Syntax errors but it seemed using a temporary table was a better solution. If you can see a way of speeding up the original query just substitute Test for TR_RELATED that would be great. Otherwise materialized views is something I did look into, so maybe that is the way to go. If I was using SQL I would create a batch in SSIS so I need something similar maybe a Pipeline.